# interval tree clocks

Tags: concurrency

I understand how vector clocks detect concurrent events, but they are designed for a fixed number of nodes, so we can't easily add and remove nodes. And with interval tree clock we can.

Could you help me grasp how they work: [Interval Tree Clocks: A Logical Clock for Dynamic Systems](http://gsd.di.uminho.pt/members/cbm/ps/itc2008.pdf). I don't understand the graphic notation. Some examples with explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pierre Chapuis gave [a short introduction](https://blog.separateconcerns.com/2017-05-07-itc.html). Maybe that can help you out?